# Html.ActionLink MVC3 ASPX / v. ?=

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

when I use the following actionlink:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Study Cases", "Index", "CourseCases", new { id = Model.ID }, new { @class = "t-button", @style = "width:240px; color:white; text-align:center" })%>
```

The url address in the browser is:

```
http://localhost:11111/CourseCases/Index/9
```

How can I change it so the url will be

```
 http://localhost:11111/CourseCases?courseId=9
```

It works when I use:

```
 return RedirectToAction("Index", "CourseCases", new { courseId = id });
```

in the controller.
Thanks in adance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
    "Study Cases", 
    "Index", 
    "CourseCases", 
    new { courseId = Model.ID }, 
    new { 
        @class = "t-button", 
        @style = "width:240px; color:white; text-align:center" 
    }
) %>
```

The reason why your code generates `http://localhost:11111/CourseCases/Index/9` is because the `{id}` is used by the default route that was generated when you created your ASP.NET MVC 3 application, so when you specify `id = Model.ID` it will match the route pattern definition in your Global.asax which is `{controller}/{action}/{id}` thus you get `CourseCases/Index/9`.